# How do I update a value based on the dense_rank result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query (SQL Server 2017) that finds two different discounts on the same date.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT    [date_id], [good_id], [store_id], [name_promo_mech], [discount],
                       RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [date_id], [good_id], [store_id], [name_promo_mech]
                       ORDER BY [discount]) + 
                       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [date_id], [good_id], [store_id], [name_promo_mech]
                       ORDER BY [discount] DESC) - 1

                       FROM [dbo].[ds_promo_list_by_day_new] AS PL
                       )

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1;
GO
```

Query result:

```
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| date_id    | store_id | good_id | name_promo_mech | discount | RN |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 3        | 98398   | January 2017    | 15       | 2  |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 3        | 98398   | January 2017    | 40       | 2  |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 5        | 98398   | January 2017    | 15       | 3  |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 5        | 98398   | January 2017    | 40       | 3  |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
| 2017-01-01 | 5        | 98398   | January 2017    | 30       | 3  |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+----+
```

Now I want to make the discounts the same for all unique good_id, store_id, name_promo_merch in the source table. There is a rule for this. For example, for the row good_id = 98398, store_id = 3, name_promo_mech = N'january 2017' there were 10 entries with a 15 discount, and 20 with a 40 discount, then the 15 discount should be replaced with 40. However, if the number of entries for each discount was the same, then the maximum discount is set for all of them.

Can I do this? The number of rows in the source table is about 100 million.

Comment: Your description does not match the actual sample data.  Please fix this.

Comment: To state the obviously, you would use a `UPDATE` statement (you can use `UPDATE` against CTE, provided it is [updatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-using-a-recursive-cte-in-an-update-statement)). Sample data and expect results will help us help you too.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!  And why are you ignoring the first row if you want all the values to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is set the value to the *mode* (a statistical term for the most common value) on each date and combination of whatever.  You can use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select pl.*,
             first_value(discount) over (partition by date_id, good_id, store_id, name_promo_mech order by cnt desc, discount desc) as mode_discount
      from (select pl.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by date_id, good_id, store_id, name_promo_mech, discount) as cnt
            from ds_promo_list_by_day_new pl
           ) pl
     )
update toupdate
    set discount = mode_discount
    where mode_discount <> discount;
```

The subquery counts the number of values for each discount for each whatever on each day.  The outer query gets the discount with the largest count, and in the case of ties, the larger value.

The rest is a simple `update`.